# Injecting Files in Folder Automatically

Tags: php

I currently am using a framework where I have to manually configure the models. I am trying to make it so that the models are injected automatically.

Here is the manual process:

```
require 'resources/model/model.php';
// create new "model" (and pass the database connection)
$this->model = new Model($this->db);
```

Here is my attempt of automating the process:

```
    $modelPath = 'resources/model/';

    $files = scandir($modelPath); 
    foreach($files as $file){
        if(is_file($modelPath.$file)){
            $fileName = $file;
            $modelName = str_replace(".php","",$fileName);

            require $modelPath . $fileName;
            // create new "model" (and pass the database connection)
            ${'this->' . $modelName} = new $modelName($this->db);
        }
    }
```

I think I might be doing my dynamic vars incorrectly because this method is not working.

Comment: are you trying to emulate [Autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)?

Comment: and I think it should be `$this->$modelName = new $modelName($this->db);`

Comment: Similar but I don't see how auto load reads all classes from all files in a directory. @bansi

Comment: I'll give that a shot when I get the chance

Comment: autoload gets invoked only when it cannot find the class you are referring in the already loaded.

Comment: Your answer above solved it! It's always something simple @bansi

Comment: nice to hear it is solved